# Is there a thin metal film that I can solder wires to?

Tags: soldering, conductive, metal-film

For instance, I bought some Dremel bits and inside the packaging were these small extremely thin pieces of metal film. Not sure what they were used for or what metal they were made out of.

It accepts solder and I was able to connect wires to it. Is there a specific name for this type of material and does anyone know where I can get more?

I ended up using it as a makeshift "connector pad" to add surface area to the end of a tiny wire I was using to connect to a battery.

Comment: Copper tape? It's thin and you can solder to it, but I have no idea whether that's what came with your bits. I'll leave the shopping to you.

Comment: `extremely thin pieces of metal film` ... you did not describe it very well .... the metal strips were probably inside a plastic jacket with a barcode printed on it ...... that is the theft prevention tag ..... it sets off an alarm at the store entrance if it is not deactivated at a checkout .......... http://www.eassecuritytags.com/uploads/pic/DR-label-barcode-ZLDRS2.jpg

Comment: the thing that you seek is used for holding stained glass pieces together . . . . . . . . . ................ see part #2 step #5 here  https://www.wikihow.com/Make-Stained-Glass

Answer (score 1):

Nickel strip solders easily and well.  You most often see nickel strip as the interconnection metal between individual cells inside battery packs.  These strips are readily available from many suppliers and even on eBay.

Look for something called "tabbing strips".

Answer (score 0):

Tin plated brass is a common solution

Comment: ok great and where can this be purchased typically?

Comment: @Vbs That's up to you to find out. We cannot recommend places to purchase it because of the rules.

Comment: We use to.use liquid tin on cut strips per etch folds and make RF shields, but many now are tin plated Cr-Steel

Comment: You can also get male and female connector leads, they can be crimped on or soldered on, Digikey has all kinds available.

Comment: @Vbs  We designed our own custom tin-plated brass contacts etched in a PCB shop.